# can't redirect user to a certain page after login

Tags: django

so i'm working on a django project, i'm storing users info in phpmyadmin database, the signup process works well, but when a user tries to login , it just reloads the page, i tried to get the values of a record from the table if the username and password are correct (for example, username : ff, pass : ff1, if those are correct, it will display the values from the table, id : 2, email: dd@gg.com, username : ff, password : ff1)

views.py :

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
import mysql.connector
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user_obj = None 
        # connect to MySQL database
        try:
            cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='', database='projet')
            cursor = cnx.cursor()
        except mysql.connector.Error as error:
            print("Failed to connect to database: {}".format(error))
        
        # retrieve user from database
        query = "SELECT * FROM projetpythonn_user WHERE username=%s AND password=%s"
        cursor.execute(query, (username, password))
        user = cursor.fetchone()
        print(user)
        
        
        if user is not None:
            # create Django User object from database user
            try:
                user_obj = User.objects.get(username=user[1])
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                print("User doesn't exist")
                
            #user = authenticate(request, username=user[1], password=user[2])
            #if user is not None:
                # login user
                #login(request, user)
            
            login(request, user_obj)
                
                # redirect to YouTube
            return redirect('/topic/')
            
        # if authentication fails, render login page with error message
        message = 'Invalid username or password'
        context = {'message': message}
        return render(request, 'login.html', context)
    
    # if request method is GET, render login page
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

nothing really helped after thousands of tries

Comment: why use `raw query` to verify user creds and then `authenticate` again?

Comment: @HemalPatel this is new to me to be honest

Comment: Refer this [Tutorial](https://ordinarycoders.com/blog/article/django-user-register-login-logout). you will learn about registering user and login.

Comment: @Hemal Patel now i'm facing this issue 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta',  (i edited the code so you could see the latest update)

Comment: start with a fresh project.

Comment: @HemalPatel i already tried that